# Fetching address using latitude ,longitude in GoogleMaps (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

[image]

I got Following Error

```
{
    "error_message" = "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 183.82.16.154, with empty referer";
    results = (
    );
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
}
```

Please anyone give solution, Thank U.

Comment: have you copied the correct API key to the project?

Comment: This my url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)&key=KEY"   "AIzaSyBWppXpsMgHFqERI2OFQGjIbALOo4f8Omg"->key

Comment: please upload your code when you hit this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Creating the key google asks you to set restrictions select none there as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: thanks for the appreciation kindly please upvote too

Comment: You should not create unrestricted public keys, you should restrict public keys to domains owned or controlled by you.